# Regular expression to remove a substring between two characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove anything between `<` and `>` including (`<` and `>`) from my string with regular expression. Here are few examples.

`Hi<friends>and<family>` it should give `Hiand`

`<Rekha Verma>rekha@gmail.com` then it should give `rekha@gmail.com`

`Reva Patel` it should give `Reva Patel`

`<Reva Patel>revapatel@gmail.com,<rekha Verma>rekha@gmail.com` it should give
`revapatel@gmail.com,rekha@gmail.com`

Can anyone please give me a regular expression for this? I need to implement it in Java.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try using the regex:

```
<.*?>
```

For example:

```
String s = "Hi<friends>and<family>";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("<.*?>", ""));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

Comment: -1 this won't work. Why do you have the first and last / in your regex?

Comment: It didn't work for me too. I was using vscode

Answer (score 0):

Give this code segment a try!

```
String str = "Hi<family>and</family>test";       

for (int i = 0; i < str.split("</?[a-z]+>").length; i++)
  System.out.println(str.split("</?[a-z]+>")[i]);
```