# How to build a regex for fixed characters?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to develop a regular expression for matching fixed characters. Below is the example:

```
String test = "<P>This is test. <A HREF="www.google.com">Google</A></P><P>Again this is a test. <A HREF="www.facebook.com">Facebook</A></P>";
```

I want to replace the block, having content starting with `<A HREF=` and ending with `>`, with the empty space. Can anyone tell me the regex for the same?

Output should be: `<P>This is test. Google</A></P><P>Again this is a test. Facebook</A></P>`

Edit: Some people are trying to relate this question to the one which specifies about regex and XHTML parsing. Well, I'm trying to match a block of characters in a java. So it clearly has not any relation with the XHTML parsing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: You can use this answer as a reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758653/regular-expression-to-remove-a-substring-between-two-characters

Comment: What have you tried, Stack overflow is a place to ask and answer questions. Not somewhere to get people to do your work for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture those strings with `<A.+?>` and replace them with empty strings. The `?` here ensures non-greedy matching.